# Decomposition of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I want to decompose a diagonal matrix $\Lambda \in R^{n \times n}$ such that $$ \Lambda \approx A\Sigma A^T $$ where $\Sigma \in R^{k \times k}$ is a diagonal matrix and $A \in R^{n \times k}$ is a dense matrix (or it is non-diagonal matrix), and $k < n$. Is there any decomposition which can be used to solve the above problem? I have asked the same question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376822/decomposition-of-a-diagonal-matrix

Edit: The number of zero elements in each row and column of $A$ matrix should not be greater than half the size of the row and column respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of explanation, suppose that 
$$
\Lambda = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ && \ddots \\ &&& \lambda_n}
$$ 
with $|\lambda_1| \geq |\lambda_2| \geq \cdots \geq |\lambda_n|$.  The [Eckart-Young theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) tells us that the best rank-$k$ approximation (or at least one of the best rank-$k$ approximations) of $\Lambda$ (relative to the Frobenius norm or induced $2$-norm) will be the diagonal matrix
$$
\Lambda^{(k)} = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_k \\&&&0\\&&&&\ddots\\ &&&&&0}
$$
We can write $\Lambda^{(k)} = M DM^T$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{\sqrt{|\lambda_1|}\\ & \ddots \\ && \sqrt{|\lambda_k|}\\&\mathbf 0_{(n-k)\times k}}
$$
and $D$ is a $k\times k$ diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal.  If $U$ is an orthogonal matrix that satisfies $UD = DU$, then we have
$$
(MU)D(MU)^T = MUDU^TM^T = MDUU^TM = MDM^T = \Lambda^{(k)}
$$
I suspect that selecting a dense orthogonal matrix satisfying $UD = DU$ will give you a good result.

---

Regarding orthogonal matrices that commute with $D$: if $D$ is such that the $1$s and $-1$s are grouped together, then we have
$$
D = \pmatrix{I_{p \times p} \\ & - I_{(n-p)\times (n-p)}}
$$
An orthogonal matrix $U$ will satisfy $UD = DU$ if and only if it is conformably block-diagonal, i.e. if and only if we have
$$
U = \pmatrix{U_{p \times p}^{(1)} & 0\\ 0 & U_{(n-p) \times (n-p)}^{(2)}}
$$
and notably, the above $U$ will be orthogonal if and only if both $U^{(1)}$ and $U^{(2)}$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the $MU$ matrix has $n-k$ columns and rows completely 0 equal to zero. I want the matrix to be dense, and also it is not necessary to have minimum Frobenius norm. The main condition is that $A\Sigma A^T$ should be closed to diagonal matrix and $A$ is dense.